# Oracle database substring :: extract IP from URL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field I can get to with a select statement that have:

```
https://<some IPv4 address>:someport/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyy
```

where `xxxxxxx` and `yyyyyyy` may vary.

How do I trim off the left and right unwanted data to just get the IP?

Also that element may look like a jdbc string.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data would really help.  You have not shown where the "IP" is in the string.

Comment: URL parsing its an entire topic of its own. If you want to ask a specific question, you should say: what oracle product, component, and origin of the URL... and if you tried any oracle provided tools. The "left-hand side" of a URL is human-readable, but a parser should recognize: IPv4, IPV6, FQDNs, and IDNs (and anything else added in the last 5 years since I last looked at this). Oh yeah, and port numbers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the IP is before the `:someport`.. SO hid it because it's inside `<` and `>`. I edited the question so it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Good, old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` might help - take part between `//` and the following `/` or `:`, if it exists:

```
SQL> with test (url) as
  2    (select 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881996/' from dual union all
  3     select 'https://localhost:8008/whatever' from dual)
  4  select
  5    substr(url,
  6           instr(url, '//') + 2,
  7           case when instr(url, ':', 1, 2) = 0 then instr(url, '/', 1, 3)
  8                else instr(url, ':', 1, 2)
  9           end - instr(url, '//') - 2
 10          ) result
 11  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stackoverflow.com
localhost

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

other way using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

```
select
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('https://:someport/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyy','[^:]+',1,3),
    '[^/]+',1,1
  )
from dual;
```

result : someport

```
select
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('https://<some IPv4 address>:someport/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyy','[^//]+',1,2),
    '[^:]+',1,1
  )
from dual;
```

result : some IPv4 address